# Context Menu Delete Option

Tags: unity, context-menu, permanent-delete

Context menu delete option not found in Ubuntu 18. Do not like the extra steps of "Trash Can", want to flush immediately instead of having to take the stinky garbage out later. Have used that option since the first of the gnome/nautilus desktop iterations. Would like it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 18.10 you will need to start Nautilus, your file manager, and click on the [Application Menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-introduction.html.en#appmenu) at the top of your screen. This opens a menu where you may access the preferences. From there, you should be able to follow user [Gounou's advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088665/12864) to:

> Select the Behavior tab, Under Trash check mark “Include a Delete command that bypasses Trash“. Click on Close.

Checking [another page of the 18.10 Desktop guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-delete.html.en), I see you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete selected items immediately, bypassing the temporary Trash storage.

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.04 the option is now named "Show action to permanently delete files and folders" though functionally seem identical.

Answer (score 3):

From the desktop, click on **Files** and select **Home**.

Files : [image]

Move the cursor to the top of the screen and click on **Edit**, then **Preferences** from the drop down menu to open the Files Preferences window.

Select the Behavior tab, Under Trash check mark “Include a Delete command that bypasses Trash“. Click on Close.

Source : https://www.avoiderrors.com/ubuntu-delete-context-menu/

I've tested it on Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: I have just installed Ubuntu 18.10 onto a new computer with Windows 10, did a dual boot installation. Used the default settings on the installation and there is no "Edit" option. I don't know how to get there from here.

Comment: Unity has control of my desktop and there are no "Menu" options at the top of my screen.

Comment: I've added a picture.

Comment: There is no "Edit" option in the "Files" menus. There is only a "Files" option. That is what was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Open "Files" the nautilus file manager. At the top of the screen select "Files" menu option, then >"Preferences". A window will open with tabs, select "Behavior" tab and at the bottom there will be a check-mark option "Show action to permanently delete files and folders".